# Vertically Aligning Text in a Div

Tags: html, css

im trying to create a website, but im having trouble with 2 parts; 
1. I am unable to vertically align the Website title vertically so that its is in the middle of the div.
2. Im trying to left align the menu table with the header div right above it and make it stay as such for all browser types.

I have tried to do different things to get both the above to work, but nothing seems to work and am unable to align either of the elements. Could someone help me please.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Game Portal</title>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color: black;
            }
            h1.header{
                font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif; 
                font-weight: bold; 
                font-size: 30px; 
                color: #fff; 
                text-transform: uppercase; 
            }
            #headerdiv{
                margin: 0px auto; 
                border: 1px solid red; 
                width: 70%; 
                height: 100px;
                padding-top:30px;
            }
            th, td {
                padding: 15px;
                table-layout: fixed;
                width: 180px;
                height: 75px;
                padding: 0px;
                border-right-style: solid;
                border-left-style: solid;
                border-width: 1px;
                border-color: #808080;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            td {
                text-align: center;
                font-family:"Times New Roman", Helvetica, sans-serif; 
                font-size: 15pt;
                border-radius:5px
                height: 100px;
            }
            a{
                color: #808080; 
            }
            #titleSize{
                font-size: 25px;
            }
            #nav {
                line-height:30px;
                background-color:#4D4D4D;
                height:80px;
                width:100%;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="headerdiv">
            <h1 class="header">game<span id="titleSize">portal</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <table style="background-color: #4D4D4D; padding-left: 15%;">
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="">Home</a></td>
                    <td><a href="UnderConstruction.html">Games</a></td>
                    <td><a href="UnderConstruction.html">News</a></td>
                    <td><a href="UnderConstruction.html">Contact Us</a></td>
                </tr>
            <table> 
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried messing with the positions (abs, fixed, relative) as well as with the margins, but nothing seems to move either of the elements. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is through padding:

```
  #headerdiv{
            width: 200px; 
            margin:0px auto; 
            border: 1px solid red; 
            width: 70%; 
            height: 70px;
            padding-top:30px;
  }
```

Here `height` has been changed and the rest to 100 has been added to `padding-top`

Comment: that didnt work :( it still wont move, it continues to stay on the top left corner of the div

Comment: i trust the code should work, but for some reason it wont work with my code.

Comment: open the fiddle above and compare code. You must not be posting the entire code then.

Comment: Just to be clear, the only thing that is vertical aligned to middle is the GAMER.. text inside the red box. If you were expecting to align something else then let me know

Comment: nvm, i got it to work with ur code, my server wasnt refreshing the new html file, so i simply restarted it and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ovLhjmwb/

For example: Is more easy to have a container that contains all the child elements (and give it a width)

```
        .container {
            width: 400px;
            margin: auto;
        }
```

Also, vertical aligned text, is a little difficult to do, the easiest way is to use the vertical-align  property (that comes with table elements)

```
        #headerdiv table{
            vertical-align: middle;                
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I guess there are some more probs. For example use more HTML5 tags and not so many of ID's or classes. Keep your DOM-tree as simple as possible. You will get a better structure and your xode is more readable. BTW I fixed your problems in my solution as well.

HTML:

```
<header>
  <h1>Game<span>Portal</span></h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="UnderConstruction.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="UnderConstruction.html">Games</a></li>
    <li><a href="UnderConstruction.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="UnderConstruction.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  background: black;
}
header {
  width: 70%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
header h1 {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 30px; 
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top:13px;
}
header h1 span {
  font-size: 25px;
}
nav {
  width:70%;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:left;
  height: 100px;
  background: #4D4D4D;
}
nav ul {
  margin-left:-40px;
}
nav ul li {
  float:left;
  list-style-type:none;
}
nav ul li a{
  color: #808080;
  height: 62px;
  padding:38px 20px 0 20px;
  border-left:1px solid #808080;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15pt;
}
```

Comment: how would i vertically align the text in the list then?

Comment: Do it with padding! As you can see in my example. nav ul li a {padding: ....} <- there is a fixed height of 62 px and the rest is padding. So the whole area around the a-tag is clickable.